# Spring oAuth2 Concurrent Request Deadlock

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using **org.springframework.security.oauth2** library and **MySQL 5.5.58**

Most of the time it works as expected without any issue. 
However, it seems that when **multiple requests** to "/oauth/token" occurs at the exact same time (each on a different server node), the servers is fighting for the db record and there is a deadlock:

`Handling error: DeadlockLoserDataAccessException, PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [delete from oauth_access_token where token_id = ?]; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

Has anyone else seen this issue? How can I avoid that behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: No one? really?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue, but I don't know how to solve it yet. Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This concurrency issue causes that 2 oauth_access_token with the same token_id are generated.
Thus, later on when the JdbcTokenStore tries to get the oauth_access_token by its key (token_id) or delete it, the operation may probably fail due to 
NonUniqueResultException or DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.

My solution was to update the oauth_access_token schema to have a unique constraint on the token_id, in order to avoid the imporper duplication in the first place.
Note that it does mean that the second request would fail (which is redundant anyway), but at least there is one and only one token for this user, and the data will remain valid and not corrupted.

Additionally, I've extended the JdbcTokenStore as my CustomTokenStore widening the error handling and cleanup in order to keep the database in its stable state.

```
@Override
public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(OAuth2AccessToken token) {
    try{
        return super.readAuthentication(token.getValue());
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e){
        OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = token.getRefreshToken();
        removeRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        removeAccessToken(token);
        logger().error("readAuthentication", e);
        throw e;
    }
}

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    logger().info("getAccessToken begin");
    try{
        return super.getAccessToken(authentication);
    }
    catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException e){
        logger().error("getAccessToken", e);
        safeRemoveAllAccessToken(authentication);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e){
        logger().error("getAccessToken", e);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(String token) {
    try{
        OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = super.readAuthentication(token);

        if(oAuth2Authentication == null){
            removeAccessToken(token);
            removeRefreshToken(token);
        }
        return oAuth2Authentication;
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e){
        logger().error("readAuthentication", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```